# Result of a definite integral as a function of extra parameters

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a definite integral with respect to dE for a function that depends on E and x, x being another parameter that I will use later. I defined a function of x that could help me with this, but it does not seem to work. When I give the new function a certain value--such as 1 or 10--it always returns 0. Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
from numpy import arange

gg=100.0
ms=100.0

def integrand(E, xx):
    return (gg/2*pi)*E*(E**2-ms**2)**(1/2)/(np.exp(E*xx*ms)-1)

def nn(x):
    return quad(integrand, ms, np.inf, args=(x))  ## quad(funcion, lim inf, lim sup, args)
```

What I need is to be able to later call the function nn with the parameter x being the variable.

Comment: You need to supply a value for `E` to the integrand.  If `nn` only takes `x` as an argument, then it needs to figure out what `E` is so it can add it to `args`.

Comment: Also, `(x)` is not a tuple, due to quirks of how Python parses parentheses.  You probably want `(x,)`.

Comment: @MatthewWoodruff But E is my integration variable, it can take any value from ms = 100 to Inf.

Comment: Oh, I see about `E`, that makes sense.  Do make sure that `args` is a tuple however.  But anyway, you're asking numpy to integrate numerically between 100 and inf?  I don't *know* that it's impossible, but I can't see how numpy can be expected to do that correctly.  Have you tried using a finite upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define all the values outside of the function:

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

gg = 100.0
ms = 100.0
xx = 5.0
ms = 1.0


def integrand(E):
    return (gg / 2 * pi) * E * (E ** 2 - ms ** 2) ** (1 / 2) / (np.exp(E * xx * ms) - 1)


val, err = quad(integrand, ms, np.inf)
print(val)
```

```
0.16712443596152543
```